# tweaking rangeslider height in plotly to prevent it from overlapping with subplots?

Tags: plotly-python

The rangeslider is too thick and overlaps with the next subplot. I can increase the vertical spacing between the subplots, or the overall plot height (as suggested here: https://community.plotly.com/t/rangeslider-overlaps-with-subplots/35169) but this makes the plot disproportional, and gets worse as the number of subplots increases. The rangeslider is just too thick.

[image]

Can I change just the height of the rangeslider?

Here's an MWE:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

import plotly.graph_objects as go 
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

n_plots = 2

data = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(n_plots):
    data[i] = np.random.randn(100)
data

fig = make_subplots(
    rows = n_plots,
    cols = 1,
    vertical_spacing = 0.1,
    shared_xaxes = True
)

for i in range(n_plots):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            y = data[i]
        ),
        row = 1+i, col = 1
    )

fig.update_layout(
    height = 800,
    width = 800,
    xaxis_rangeslider_visible = True,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can change the rangeslider height (thickness) using:

```
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_rangeslider_visible = True,
    xaxis_rangeslider_thickness = 0.04
)
```

[image]

For the rangeslider associated with the n-th x-axis, you would use:  `xaxisn_rangeslider_thickness`

Comment: Also, modifying `vertical_spacing` attribute along with the answers suggested `xaxis_rangeslider_thickness` will provide satisfying results.